# Do Applovin ads disappear occasionally?

Tags: ios, ads, applovin

We have several `iOS` apps using `chartboost` and `applovin`. During testing both appeared together, but today the first one was approved in the app store and we noticed that `applovin` `ads` aren't appearing. I played around with some settings in the dashboard and got them back after a while. Is that a known phenomenon? Do I need to watch over them constantly? What might've caused it?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is probably [frequency capping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_capping). Most ad networks, AppLovin included, allow you to restrict the number of times per hour/day/etc that a user will see ads. Double check those settings in your dashboard.